# Change event in Autocomplete jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

in my project im using the jQuery Autocomplete which is working great.
the problem is, that i want to handle a situation were a user changes the input of the text.
for ex. the data contains ("prov 1", "prov 2"), the user choose from the menu "prov 1" but then changed it to "prov 2" by changing the 1 with 2.
i implemented the "change" event in the js but the ui.item is empty (i guess since the menu is not shown..)
i read that the "change" event is fired only when the text box is losing focus -> not to good for me, since the flow is selecting a "prov" and clicking button to continue.
any suggestions ??

here is my code:
JS

```
 $(element).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { query: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Label,
                            value: item.Label,
                            realValue: item.Value
                        };
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var hiddenFieldName = $(this).attr('data-value-id');
            $('#' + hiddenFieldName).val(ui.item.realValue);
            hiddenFieldName = $(this).attr('data-value-name');
            $('#' + hiddenFieldName).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            alert('changed');
            if (!ui.item) {                    
                alert('no value'); /* IS FIRED */
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the keypress event handler -- http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
```

to this:

```
input: function (event, ui) {
```

---

Or you can try with this:

```
 $(element).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        //all your code but not change: function
 }).on('input', function(e){
     alert('changed');
     if (this.value.length <== 0) {                    
        alert('no value'); /* IS FIRED */
     } else {
        alert(this.value);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hi, thank's for you help, but still didn't solve the main issue. the thing is that when the user is retyping, i lose the ui element, since the selected is already triggered so that is the last id & name i get, although the user changed the name. is there a way to re-enter the source then user changes input ???